# How to convert an char array to double value in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, atoi

importing library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>  
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
const int size = 100;
```

getting the user input for dollar amount

```
int main()
{
    void mstold(char[]);
    char array[size];
    cout << "enter the amount" << endl;
    cin >> array;
    // cout<<strlen(array)<<endl;
    mstold(array);
}
```

`mstold` function to extract only the digits and decimal from the user given dollar amount

```
void mstold(char array[])
{
    int count = 0;
    // char pure[strlen(array)];
    int index_pure = 0;

    // counting the number of significant values which are to be extracted
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++)
        // if ((int(array[i]) < 58 and int(array[i]) > 48) or (array[i] == ','))
        if ((int(array[i]) < 58 and int(array[i]) > 48) or (array[i] == '.'))
        {
            count++;
        }
    cout << "count" << endl;

    cout << count << endl;
    char pure[count + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++)
        // if ((int(array[i]) < 58 and int(array[i]) > 48) or (array[i] == ','))
        if ((int(array[i]) < 58 and int(array[i]) > 48) or (array[i] == '.'))
        {
            pure[index_pure] = array[i];
            cout << int(array[i]) << endl;
            ++index_pure;
        }
    pure[index_pure] = '\0';
    
    cout << "pure" << endl;

    // created a array name pure which contains only digit and decimal.
    // however this is an array.
    // i need to convert this array of char to a double type variable.

    cout << pure << endl;

    // this line causing error

    long double money = _atof_l(pure);
    cout << money << endl;

    // atoi is working and converting the string array to int
    // however the array to double is not working
}
```

Comment: input to std::string, then use std::stod ("C" style arrays just make things more complicated, only use them if you need that little bit more control on performance/memory usage)

Comment: you should use the C++ versions of the c headers. You are already including `cstdlib`, so you don't need to include `stdlib.h` three times more. Same for `cmath` vs `math.h`

Comment: `strtod` is the floating-point equivalent to `strtol` (which is what you should use whenever `atoi` pops into your head).  Pepjin's suggestion of `std::stod` is good also, if you want to handle errors via exceptions.